# $\mathfrak{p}_x \subset \mathfrak{p}_y$, $A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$ is a localization of $A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$. Must $\mathfrak{p}_y$ be a maximal ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I came accross this in the accepted answer of the question [In a quasicompact scheme every nonreduced point has a closed nonreduced point in its closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650108/in-a-quasicompact-scheme-every-nonreduced-point-has-a-closed-nonreduced-point-in). In this linked post, $y$ is a closed point, but the proof does not use this informatiom exiplicitly. So I want to figure out where is it required.

Since prime ideals in $A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ corresponds to prime ideals in $A$ contained in  $\mathfrak{p}_y$, the ideal $\mathfrak{p}_x$ corresponds to some prime ideal in $A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$. By definition it’s $\mathfrak{p}'_x = \{a/b: a \in \mathfrak{p}_x, b \notin  \mathfrak{p}_y\}$. The localization of $A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ at $\mathfrak{p}'_x$ is $(A_{\mathfrak{p}_y})_{\mathfrak{p}'_x} = \{(a/b)/(c/d): c \notin \mathfrak{p}_x, b, d \notin \mathfrak{p}_y\}$.

I map $(a/b)/(c/d)$ in $(A_{\mathfrak{p}_y})_{\mathfrak{p}'_x}$ to $ad/bc$ in $A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$ and map $a/b$ back to $(a/1)/(b/1)$. Everything seems fine without requiring $\mathfrak{p}_y$ a maximal ideal.

Did I miss something? Or does the statement (and the linked answer) hold without requiring $\mathfrak{p}_y$ a maximal ideal?

Sorry for kind of messing up two questions in one. And I cannot find some references for this. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there's no need for $p_y$ to be maximal in the claim you prove in your post.

There are two things going on in the linked post:

1. Every quasi-compact scheme has a closed point (and since any closed subscheme of a quasi-compact scheme is again quasi-compact, every point in a quasi-compact scheme has a closed point in its closure);
2. If $p\subset q$ are prime ideals of a ring $R$, then $R_p$ is a localization of $R_q$, so since the localization of a reduced ring is again reduced, $R_q$ reduced implies $R_p$ must also be reduced.

Combining these two statements gives the result in the link: every point in a quasi-compact scheme has a closed point in its closure, and every point in the closure of a non-reduced point must again be non-reduced, so if one has a non-reduced point in a quasi-compact scheme then it must have a non-reduced closed point in its closure.

Comment: Thank you very much. So we in fact do  have  a little stronger result in the proof: if one has a non-reduced point in a quasi-compact scheme then any point in its closure must be non-reduced too? (and then using item1 that in a quasicompact scheme, every non-empty closed set has a closed point)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.