# Affinization of a normal variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

By affinization of $X$ I mean $\text{Aff}(X) := \text{Spec}(\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X))$.  First, I claim that if $X$ is reduced, then $\text{Aff}(X)$ is reduced.  The argument goes: if $\Gamma(X, O_X)$ has a nilpotent element, i.e. a nilpotent global function, it is nonzero and nilpotent on some open affine of $X$, contradicting that $X$ is reduced.

Does this argument sound convincing?

If it does, then I have a follow up question: if $X$ is normal, does that mean $\text{Aff}(X)$ is normal?

Comment: A scheme is said to be *reduced* if all of it's local rings are reduced ring. This is same as saying, given any open set $U \subseteq X,$ the ring $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X|_U)$ is reduced. [Hartshorne, Ch. II, Ex. 2.3] Which definition you are using, it's not clear to me. I think you need some more arguments. In the case of "normal", I don't think $\text{Aff}(X)$ is normal. Take $A$ to be the infinite product of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z.$ Then localizing at each prime ideal, you will get the field $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z.$

Comment: @RghtHndSd is there a counterexample?  I can't think of one but my commutative algebra is not great.  A quick Googling turns up: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-726-algebraic-geometry-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_726s09_lec11_more_schemes.pdf which seems to indicate that $Spec(A)$ is reduced iff $A$ has no nonzero nilpotents

Comment: Another reference with proof: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IZ
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8150/does-localization-preserve-reducedness

Comment: Ah, indeed, my example does not work. It would have involved taking an infinite product.

Comment: @Krish, thanks for the comment.  What if $X$ is a "reasonable" scheme, e.g. say quasicompact, quasiseparated, even separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fact:* Let $X$ be a scheme. Consider the following assertions:

$(i)$ Every connected component of $X$ is irreducible.

$(ii)$ $X$ is the disjoint union of its irreducible components.

$(iii)$ For all $x \in X,$ the nilradical of the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is a prime ideal.

Then we have the following implications: $(i) \Rightarrow (ii) \Rightarrow (iii).$ In addition if the scheme $X$ is locally Noetherian then all the three are equivalent.

As a corollary of the above fact we get that, if $X$ is connected and locally Noetherian then $X$ is integral if and only if for all $x \in X,$ the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is a domain.

***Claim:*** Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian normal scheme, and let $U \subseteq X$ be a connected open subset. Then $\Gamma(U, \mathcal O_X)$ is a normal domain.

We can assume $X=U,$ i.e. $X$ is connected. Then $X$ is integral (from the above discussion). Let $K(X)$ be the function field of $X$ and let $t \in K(X)$ be integral over $A=\Gamma(X, \mathcal O_X).$ Now $X$ is normal and hence $t \in \mathcal O_{X,x}, \forall x \in X.$ This shows that $t \in A.$